# Sonar missing dependencies between Maven modules

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, dependencies, sonarqube

I've searched through several questions related to multi-module maven projects and sonar, but those were mostly about aggregating code coverage metrics.

I have a multi-module maven project being analyzed by sonar.
If I run the analysis straight from the terminal using `mvn sonar:sonar` the resulting analysis will display the dependencies between the maven modules in the Design page.

However, if I run the analysis by invoking sonar-runner via Jenkins the resulting analysis will have missed the dependencies between the maven modules.

Here's a snippet of the top-level pom where I set sonar parameters:

```xml
<profile>
    <id>sonar</id>
    <activation>
        <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
    </activation>
    <properties>
        <sonar.jdbc.url>
            jdbc:mysql://myhost:3306/sonar?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=utf8
        </sonar.jdbc.url>
        <sonar.jdbc.username>sonar</sonar.jdbc.username>
        <sonar.jdbc.password>sonar</sonar.jdbc.password>
        <sonar.host.url>http://myhost:9999</sonar.host.url>
        <sonar.java.source>1.7</sonar.java.source>
        <sonar.login>jenkins</sonar.login>
        <sonar.password>jenkins</sonar.password>
    </properties>
</profile>
```

On Jenkins I configured the job to do a `clean install -DskipTests=true` in the build step followed by a post-build action to run Sonar.

I'm using Maven version 3.0.5, SonarQube version 3.7, Sonar Runner 2.3 and Java 1.7.0_45.

Any idea of what can I be missing in my configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed the SonarQube Maven bootstrapper relies on Maven to get the dependencies (either on modules or on external libraries). But SonarRunner doesn't have access to such kind of information and that's why when you analyse a project with SonarRunner you don't get any information about external dependencies.

Comment: It seems that if I run `mvn sonar:sonar` from command line I do get the inter-module dependencies in the design page. But if I do the same from jenkins as a post-build step, the dependencies are not shown. Any idea why?

Comment: With some experimentation I found that the inter-module dependencies appear in the design page if I DO NOT set the property `sonar.branch`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok if you are using Jenkins, you need to install Sonar Plugin and set parameters. Then, you need to create a job and run maven target:

```
clean install
```

After that, mark Sonar checkbok. Run your job and you should see your code coverage.

PS: If you are using module you must have pom-root with all your modules.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time, but the problem I described is not related to code coverage. I have Sonar Plugin installed and I can build and analyse the project from Jenkins. My problem is about inter-module dependencies. The dependencies you would expect to see between the modules on the SonarQube Design page.